# How to set file location in application properties - Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, properties, path

I have a Spring Boot application, the code need to access a file under resources/templates folder. 
here is my application.properties file:

```
    pont.email.template.location=templates/mailTemplate.html
```

This is the java file where I use the variable:

```
    @Value("${pont.email.template.location}") 
    private String templateLocation;
    ----------------
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(templateLocation));
```

The problem is not get the varibale, it returns correctly, The problem is that the application do not found any file for this path.

I always get

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: templates/mailTemplate.html (No such file or directory)
```

I have checked that the file is in the path..

what is wrong in my code?
Help please, thanks.

Comment: may be, try classpath:templates/mailTemplate.html

Comment: Considering that the error happens when attempting to read the file, the code you posted right now is less relevant. Please share the code you use to read the file and add it to your question.

Comment: @Cooshal whit this path returns the same error:         java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:templates/mailTemplate.html (No such file or directory)

Comment: @g00glen00b already done, thanks!

Comment: What is the **exact location** of this file? Is it `src/main/resources/templates`?

Comment: @Cooshal I dont think that the problem will be in that code because when I do it localy, it works fine (in dev enviroment) but when I run pre enviromen I get this error. I have 2 enviroments dev (in my pc) and pre, where i use to deploy a jar file in a  aws server.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes that's correct.

Comment: Then this won't work. Use `classpath:templates/mailTemplate.html` and instead of `String` use `Resource` as a type. Then use `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(templaceLocation.getInputStream());` instead of reading a file. Reading a file doesn't work in a JAR as it has to point to a file system resource. This is only the case with an unpacked JAR (or in dev where you don't have a jar at all).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot read a `File` from inside a JAR. This fails due to the fact that the `File` has to point to an actual file resource on the file system and not something inside a JAR.

Let Spring do the heavy lifting and use the [`Resource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources) abstraction to hide the nasty internals. So instead of using a `String` use a `Resource` and prefix the value of the property with `classpath:` to make sure it is loaded from the classpath. Then use an `InputStreamReader` instead of `FileReader` to obtain the information you need.

```
@Value("${pont.email.template.location}") 
private Resource templateLocation;
----------------
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(templateLocation.getInputStream()));
```

In your `application.properties` prefix with `classpath:`.

```
pont.email.template.location=classpath:templates/mailTemplate.html
```

Now it should work regardless of the environment you are running in.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @M.Deinum this woks fine form me!

Comment: +1 this worked for me! i had to resolve the filename with file.getFilename() as in
@Value("${file}")
Resource file;